# Trying to unzip tar.gz file and save it as multiple readable text files in a folder and then recompress it

Tags: python, gzip

```
import gzip
import os
os.mkdir('uncompressed')
with gzip.open("Raw_feature_count_data.tar.gz", "rt") as f:
    output=f.read()
output
```

Trying to unzip multiple feature counts text files using python, the code does unzip it but i'ts unreadable and merges all the files together. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The result of unzipping a `.tar.gz` file is a `.tar` file.  The next step would be to use Python's `tarfile` module to unpack that archive.

Comment: [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html?highlight=tar) can handle gzip directly (with mode 'r:gz'). Instead of using open method, you might also consider using extractall

Comment: @bfris That's the answer. Why not put your answer in the big answer box below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tarfile](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/tarfile.html) is the module to use. And it can handle gzip compression using the `r:gz` mode. From the examples at the [bottom of documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/tarfile.html#examples)

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("sample.tar.gz")
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```